# Change my location button position in google map ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I know this is already asked question but I tried all the solutions which is in that SO question but none of them worked so can any one tell me how to change frame of the google map my location button. I am using 1.13.23885.0 version of the google map.

1) Not working

```
    mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] init];
    mapView.tag = Tag_googleMapView;
    mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height);
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.indoorEnabled = YES;

    [mapView setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
    [mapView.settings setMyLocationButton:YES];


    [view addSubview:mapView];
    [self setupOverviewMarker:view];


    [mapView setPadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(70.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

2) Not Working

```
for (UIView *object in mapView.subviews) {
        if([[[object class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsView"] )
        {
            for(UIView *view in object.subviews) {
                if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSx_QTMButton"] ) {
                    CGRect frame = view.frame;
                    frame.origin.y = 0.0;
                    view.frame = frame;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [mapView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [mapView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Is it possible in new SDK?

Comment: where u want to put button?

Comment: @DarjiJigar it is google map in build functionality. I am not putting button any where

Comment: try this code GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-37.81969
                                                        longitude:144.966085
                                                             zoom:4];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
_mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kOverlayHeight, 0);
self.view = _mapView;

Comment: I already doing this please look in to my question

Answer (score 1):

Please try this step:

Only change line swaping:

```
Current:
[mapView setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
[mapView.settings setMyLocationButton:YES];


Chnages:
[mapView.settings setMyLocationButton:YES];
[mapView setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late, but it may help someone else.
just provide padding to your map using UIEdgeInsets as

```
googleMap.Padding = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 60, right: 0);
```

or use this

```
for (UIView *object in mapView_.subviews) {
    if([[[object class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSUISettingsView"] )
    {
        for(UIView *view in object.subviews) {
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"GMSx_QTMButton"] ) {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin.y -= 60;
                view.frame = frame;
            }
        }

    }
};
```